# spliting of output lines into mutliple lines in linux

Tags: shell

My code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="$1"

echo -n "file size:"
du="$(du $dir -hab | sort -n -r | tail -1)"
printf "%s\n" "echo "$du""
```

It's showing output as:

```
     file size:echo 0
./.config/enchant/en_US.dic
```

My expected output is:

```
file size: 0
./.config/enchant/en_US.dic
```

should be displayed like above. The path should be in a new line with one tab space.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your description of the desired output, as it doesn't match up with the appearance. Can you [edit] to make things more clear?

Comment: As previously requested, could you update your question so that the desired output and the description match up? Also, it would be useful to include an example of the output from `du "$dir" -hab | sort -n -r | tail -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you should just use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$1
printf 'file size: %s\n\t%s\n' $(du "$dir" -hab | sort -n -r | tail -1)
```

The lack of quotes around the command substitution means that word splitting is performed. The first word in the output is output on the same line as "file size: " and the second word is printed on a newline, following a tab character.

I've added some quotes around `$dir` inside the command substitution, to prevent issues with word splitting and glob expansion. The quotes around the assignment aren't necessary (but they do no harm, so you can leave them in if you want).

Comment: I am getting an error as invalid zero-length file name. should I assign a variable to $(du "$dir" -hab | sort -n -r | tail -1) or no need

Comment: I'm not sure what your input is to cause this. It sounds like `$dir` is undefined. If you showed the output of `du "$dir" -hab | sort -n -r | tail -1`, then a solution involving a tool such as awk would probably be more appropriate.